# Oracle REGEXP_LIKE match Strings containing a number

Tags: regex, oracle

I am not very good with regular expression and there is a thing i don't really understand.

I have a string : 'BSIOC_V6_560', and a list of different patterns. I need to get every pattern this string is matching with.
But I have the following try matching when i though it would not:

```
select 'True' as Response from dual where REGEXP_LIKE('BSIOC_V6_560','BSIOC_V5*');
```

I must have misunderstood something. Can somebody provide me an explanation ?

Comment: could you please complement, what you exactly have to compare. e.g. string starts with 'BSIOC_V5', string contains 'BSIOC_V5', etc.

Comment: @FrankOckenfuss These two situations can happen. Sometimes it will start with this string, sometimes it will contain it, making the pattern like `'*BSIOC_V5*'`. Hope i am clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jan answer is correct, but only for answer your question..

- character `*` (star) means **zero or more repetitions**.. in your case of BSIOC_V5, so yes! you have 0 repetitions! This sentences also return true:

  `select 'True' as Response from dual where REGEXP_LIKE('BSIOC_V6_560', 'X*');`
- character `.` (dot) means **any character**, so `.*` means zero or more repetitions of any character... so...

  `select 'True' as Response from dual where REGEXP_LIKE('BSIOC_V6_560', 'BSIOC_V5');`
   Doesn't match you can't find BSIOC_V5

  `select 'True' as Response from dual where REGEXP_LIKE('BSIOC_V6_560', 'BSIOC_V.');`
   Yes! BSIOC_V plus any character

  `select 'True' as Response from dual where REGEXP_LIKE('BSIOC_V6_560', 'BSIOC_V5.*');`
   Doesn't match, you can't find BSIOC_V5 plus something else...

I hope you will find it helpful!

Comment: Thanks ! I get now why this wasn't working the way i wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'True' as Response from dual where REGEXP_LIKE('BSIOC_V6_560','BSIOC_V5.*');
```

The point is that open ended patterns are implicitly substring matched.

```
select 'True' as Response from dual where REGEXP_LIKE('abc','b');
```

Result : True

```
select 'True' as Response from dual where REGEXP_LIKE('abc','b$');
```

Result : Empty

```
select 'True' as Response from dual where REGEXP_LIKE('abc','c$');
```

Result : True

Comment: This is a valid correction, but could you please elaborate on why `5*` was matching the `6`, how a quantifier works in regex, and why `.*` matches any number of chars? Also, please format your code so it's easier for everyone to read.